# Rails3 ActiveRecord Transactions after_commit on multiple actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9d2146ac6e4c1fdc9cc157d614b1eb9968ac6a2e/activerecord/lib/active_record/transactions.rb#L221) I can define the same method to be executed after a commit of type create or update:

```
after_commit :do_foo_bar, :on [:create, :update]
```

Well, this code results in a parsing error for me:

> can't convert Symbol into Integer

I then change it to this:

```
after_commit :do_foo_bar, :on => [:create, :update]
```

I get no errors, but nothing happens! Further investigation at the logs show me a silent and strange error:

```
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:404: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting tSTRING_CONTENT or tSTRING_DBEG or tSTRING_DVAR or tSTRING_END
...(transaction_include_action?(:[:create, :update]))
...                               ^
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:412: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
/home/nuno/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ')'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/people/1
Completed 302 Found in 7491ms (ActiveRecord: 410.6ms)
```

How can I properly do this?

Comment: TRy after_commit :do_foo_bar, :on => ["create","update"]

Comment: @Raghu same results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the version of Rails you are using is not supporting this feature on the callbacks. Check the feature request below

https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9356